# $ is undefined after opening excel ActiveXobject

Tags: jquery, activexobject

I have a local html file to do some manipulations with excel.
My scripts tags are in head as follows

```
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Excel;
    var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
    function openExcel(){
        Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Visible = true;
        return Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/Desktop/Temp/Input.xlsx").ActiveSheet;    
    }
    function begin(){
$("div").append("zzzzzzzz");
    ExcelSheet = openExcel();
$("div").append("zzzzzzzz");

}
    </head>
```

I call function "begin" on button click...
The first append gets executed but the second does not.

on console it says "'$' is undefined" after execution.
Before excution it finds JQUery
I am using IE9

Comment: Could you please test if it will work if you use `jQuery("div").append("zzzzzzzz")` instead of just writing `$("div").append("zzzzzzzz")` (just to be sure that it is only a problem with the `$`) ?

Comment: your inline `script` tag is not closed, I see `head` close instead

Comment: maybe the active x object is appending a second Jquery file, it will cause $ to be undefined?

Comment: @OweRReLoaDeD jquery is too smart for not to kill itself

Comment: Thank you. I got it fixed. I dont knwo how. I make a clean new file imported jquery and migrated my code chuck by chunck out of desperation. :S. And it works. i guess it was due to excel was in read only mode.

Comment: Excel might be using `$` as a global variable since it's commonly used when referencing cells. It's a really crappy implementation, but then again, it's ActiveX. What happens if you put it inside it's own closure and not in the window scope?

Comment: @Rigel care to show the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Braiam Works fine

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Excel;
    var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
    function openExcel(){
        Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Visible = true;
        return Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/Desktop/Temp/Input.xlsx").ActiveSheet;    
    }
    function begin(){
$("div").append("zzzzzzzz");
    ExcelSheet = openExcel();
$("div").append("zzzzzzzz");

}
</script>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Body has loaded</h1>
    <div></div>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="begin()">
</body>

</html>
```